# postgresql function "idx" is found in some machine but not in other

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Here is a query which I am executing with `PreparedStatement`

```
SELECT planner.udf_desc.* FROM planner.udf_desc WHERE id IN(3,2) ORDER BY idx(array[3,2], id);
```

I have a table with name `udf_desc` in `planner` schema.
**To make it work I installed `intarray` extension in my database**

```
create extension "intarray"
```

I am using linux machine. And I tried above in three other machines (all were linux).
But now when I tried the same thing on windows machine. It is not working and I am getting following error :

```
function idx(integer[], integer) does not exist
```

I tried it on other three windows machines, but it doesn't work.
I printed the stack trace on server console

```
18:01:40,505 ERROR [com.ers.dao.UdfDao] (default task-13) SELECT planner.udf_desc.* FROM planner.udf_desc WHERE id IN(2) ORDER BY idx(array[2], id)
18:01:40,517 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) java.sql.SQLException: ERROR: function idx(integer[], integer) does not exist
18:01:40,517 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
18:01:40,520 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   Position: 73 Query: SELECT planner.udf_desc.* FROM planner.udf_desc WHERE id IN(2) ORDER BY idx(array[2], id) Parameters: []
18:01:40,522 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:392)
18:01:40,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:351)
18:01:40,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:289)
```

Everything is same on all machines but `idx` function is working on one and not on other.

Comment: Well you need to run `create extension intarray` on your Windows installation as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did, I did everything that I did in linux system.

Comment: Apparently not. Did you commit the `create extension`? Did you get a feedback that the extension was created?

Comment: Or maybe you created the extension in the wrong database.

Comment: Or maybe in a wrong schema (I noticed that you qualified your table's name with `planner.` ... extensions and functions are exist within a specific schema, just like other DB objects, like your table; but extensions are a little bit special: they can be created once per database -- but still within a schema).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I created extension, and the query is working if I directly write it on console (either by using pgAdmin or by command line). But When same is not working with java.

Comment: Then maybe your Java program connects to a different database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name believe me it is connecting to the desired database, there nothing wrong with my code, I am using correct schema, correct db, correct table, correct datasource, installed extensions as required, code is also same. Out of 6 systems, code is not working only on windows machines. I just want a fix for it. I reported the problem to creator of "intarray" module. For now I am doing things on second tier that I wanted to be done at third tier.

Comment: believe me: in 99% of cases like that, the code is connecting to the wrong database or is using the wrong user or the wrong search_path or the permissions are wrong....

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I cross checked everything once more. The thing is it is working in some machine whether I reinstall everything from very starting. But not working in other machine with same installation method. Currently what I observed is, it is not working in any windows machine. If you are saying in 99% cases problem is with connectivity, search_path and permission. I can assure you connection is correct. May be the problem is with search_path or permission. Let me know if you can help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on AWS RDS. The solution was to drop the extension and creating it again:

```
DROP EXTENSION intarray;
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```